# How to open a lua file on text editor using windows 10

Tags: lua

I want to open a .Lua file on a text editor, I have tried most of the text editors but its still didn't let me. is there any process that i need to do to open the file like we usually doing to open it just to double click or "open with" other programs ? 
please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Can you upload your file to any file sharing service?

Comment: What operating sytem are you using? If Windows, I would suggest downloading and opening it from within Visual Code or Notepad++

Comment: i already did on notepad ++ and visual code but it keeps the same results

Comment: can i add you on any social media platform so i can send the details @EgorSkriptunoff

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of problem you may have, as any text editor should open .lua files (assuming you have some source code in those files). There *may be* lua files that include binary code, but those are rare. If you get any specific errors/messages you get when you try to open the file, you may want to include those in the description.

Comment: ok here is the problem , i want to see the source code of my team mates then, when i tried to to open the file using microsoft visual code editor it shows some random script and symbol, it didn't show the original text of the codes and i have done this for so many text editors but it still keeping me have the same result. is the code encrypted or what ?

Comment: here's what it says when i tried to open it "The file is not displayed in the editor it is because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding. Do you want to open it anyway?" and the when i click the link says to "open it anyway" it shows me random text with symbols.